# Chrome and Safari bookmarklet differences

Tags: bookmarklet

Got same bookmarklet that works on Chrome but does not on Safari (although works from console):

`javascript:(function(){document.getElementById("hnmain").width="50%"})();`

I have tried using single quotes on Safari. No errors are produced.

I am trying to use at Hacker News comments, a.i. https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9559672

Answer (score 0):

Try standard (cross-browser) way of accessing CSS properties:

```
document.getElementById("hnmain").style.width="50%";
```

Comment: Thanks, was already answered [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/192381/safari-bookmarklet-accessing-dom).